# Sublime Text 3 Plugins

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Такой вопрос, использовал раньше VisualStudio сейчас перешёл на Sublime в связи с тем что он "легче" для системы.
В Visual есть команда #region и #endregion которая скрывает кусок кода, весьма удобно, есть ли какой-то плагин для Sublime, который будет реализовывать эту функцию?

Comment: (в порядке комментария) Странный выбор. Сейчас весь хайп  с [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/).

Comment: Да, как-то попробовал Sublime так на нём и остался, весьма удобный и настраивать его можно как только душа пожелает.

Comment: Ваше дело, конечно. Но, если откроете последние англоязычные видеокурсы по Unity, вэб разработке и проч., то, не побоюсь этого слова, в 80% случаев автор  будет вас учить писать код именно в VS Code.

Comment: Да, не спорю, но самое интересное, что в случае С# что в VS Code, что в Sublime используется тот же OmniSharp, разница только в функционале, если в VS большинство вещей идет с коробки, то с Sublime нужно повозиться немного для настройки, это как + так и - можно настроить программу чисто под себя и конкретную задачу, не нагружая систему лишними функциями.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А такой вариант совсем не устраивает?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]